# How do I fix path not finding issue in husky and lint-staged?

Tags: yarnpkg, husky, lint-staged

Since my package.json and .git are not on the same level, I referred to the [custom directory of the docs](https://typicode.github.io/husky/#/?id=custom-directory).

#### error

```
yarn run v1.22.17
error Couldn't find a package.json file in "/Users/home/project"
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
husky - pre-commit hook exited with code 1 (error)
```

#### directory structure

```
project
│   .git    
│
└─── admin
│   │
│   └───frontend(using js and React)
│       │   package.json
│       └─── .husky
│   │
│   └───backend(using js and Node.js)
└─── engine(using Rust)
```

#### package.json

```
  "devDependencies": {
   ...
   "husky": "^8.0.1",
   "lint-staged": "^13.0.3",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --progress --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --progress --mode production",
    "prepare": "cd ../.. && husky install admin/frontend/.husky && husky add admin/frontend/.husky/pre-commit \"yarn run lint-staged\""
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.{js, jsx, ts, tsx}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  }
```

But when I git commit, I get the above error. how can i fix it?

Comment: changed \"cd admin/frontend && yarn run lint-staged\" and working.